# How to input chinese in empathy?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, empathy, ibus, chinese

Small problem here: I use Ibus to input chinese, until now, everything works fine, but I can't input chinese in empathy. I'm on gnome 3, enjoying the integration of empathy with the DE (so i don't want to install pidgin). Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Have you solved this problem or are you still looking for help? f this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the input area,and select the input method you installed,I just resolve the problem like you.I use fctix input method to typing Chinese.